# При переходе на Activity белый лист!

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Имеется кусочек кода,layout `timetablel.xml` существует, класс включает "activity" ,activity также указан в `AndroidManifest`.При запуске приложения ошибок нет,при переходе на проблемный activity тоже.Только вместо элементов из файла,там белый лист[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.timetablel);
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    editText4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    editText5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    editText6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    btnReady=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnReady);
    mSettings = getSharedPreferences(APP_SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    btnReady.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/Background"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="@string/timel"
    android:textColor="@color/textv"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.19">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="0">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Подъём"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textColor="@color/textv"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="time"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Введи время"
            android:textColor="@color/textv"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="0">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Завтрак"
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textColor="@color/textv"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="time"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Введи время"
            android:textColor="@color/textv"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Школа"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textColor="@color/textv"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="time"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Введи время"
            android:textColor="@color/textv"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="0">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Обед"
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:textColor="@color/textv"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="time"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Введи время"
            android:textColor="@color/textv"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Свободное время"
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/textv" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="time"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Введи время"
            android:textColor="@color/textv"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Полдник"
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textColor="@color/textv"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="time"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Введи время"
            android:textColor="@color/textv"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Готово!"
    android:id="@+id/btnReady"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.53"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Приведите разметку проблемной активити.

Comment: Сделано!(Добавил в тему)

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего проблема в весе и высоте элементов разметки.

При использовании веса высоту надо приравнять `0dip`, т.е. примерно так:

```
android:layout_weight="SOME_VALUE"
android:layout_height="0dip"
```

Также у вас у первого `TextView` вес вообще не указан. И сумма веса не совпадает, насколько я понял, с заданной в корневом элементе.

Comment: Cпасибо,сейчас буду пытаться исправлять.Но всё равно не  совсем понял,у меня есть другой layout,где такой код:

Comment: android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Привет,Анатолий!"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_weight="0.13"
        android:textColor="@color/textv"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

Comment: Но он работает!